# Is it possible to relay/forward messages from contact A to contact B using Twilio on WhatsApp?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, forwarding

I would like to be able to have a single phone number that holds a list of contacts. And then for contact A to be able to send a message to that phone number that looks like this: "Fred: Hi fred!", which would then get relayed by Twilio and sent onward to contact B named Fred like so "Alex said: Hi fred!"

So, is it even possible to relay/forward messages from contact A to contact B using Twilio considering?

If there is what would be an indicated way to go about this in python?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is absolutely possible :)
In this scenario, you need a Twilio number that acts as a "Man in the middle" and forwards all messages. There is a blog post that describes [almost the scenario you mentioned](https://www.twilio.com/blog/sms-forwarding-and-responding-using-twilio-and-javascript). The only difference is that this sample will use the phone number instead of a contact name before the colon.

```
+1 415 12341234: Hi, how  are you doing?
+1 415 56785678: Good, any you?


Instead of
Fred: Hi, how  are you doing?
Alex: Good, any you?
```

But it shouldn't be too hard to use a JSON object that maps names and phone numbers inside the Twilio function. If you want to go the extra mile, you could probably use an API to sync your contacts as well. But that only works if your address book/ contacts app has an API.

Comment: Thank you for that, once I dove in a bit I now definitely understand more of the inner working of Twilio now but I had sadly forgotten to mention I had meant on WhatsApp. I'm not that young though honestly I totally forgot SMS was a thing haha.

I currently know there are two ways to do this. Either by creating a proxy session, or by programming a bot including a flask server to capture the received messages. The first I don't grasp too well. The second seems impossible to perform due to the limitation of forced templates and not being able to forward because of the meta TOS. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'm afraid I don't know how this could work with the current restrictions :/